# how to display image from json api wordpress using picasso?

Tags: java, android, json, wordpress

i have project in android with json api to get image from blog wordpress, i'm trying to retrive image using recylerview but image can't showing

i'm using plugin wordpress JSON API, i've tried on this problem, cause i'm newbe in java and json

[this my json structed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7oJf.png)

```
//this is my code in adapter class
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int    position) {
    if (holder instanceof OriginalViewHolder) {
        final Post p = items.get(position);
        OriginalViewHolder vItem = (OriginalViewHolder) holder;
        vItem.title.setText(Html.fromHtml(p.title));
        vItem.short_content.setText(Html.fromHtml(p.excerpt));
        ((OriginalViewHolder) holder).date.setText(items.get(position).date);
        vItem.comment.setText(p.comment_count+"");

        Tools.displayImageThumbnail(ctx, p, vItem.image);

        vItem.lyt_parent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                    mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(view, p, position);
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    }
}

//thi is my second class function to display image from json
 public static void displayImageThumbnail(Context ctx, Post p, ImageView imageView){
    try{
        String url = "";
        if(p.thumbnail !=null && !p.thumbnail.equals("")) {
            url = p.thumbnail;
        }else if(p.attachments.size() > 0){
            for(Attachment a : p.attachments){
                if(a.mime_type.equals("image/jpeg") || a.mime_type.equals("image/png")){
                    url = a.url;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(url)){
            Picasso.with(ctx).load(url).into(imageView);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("WORDPRESS", "Failed when display image - "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```